# MySQL crashes daily on VPS with Ubuntu Server 12.04 - How can I find the error or conflict?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

Every day for the past four days, my website server crashes at least once. (Error establishing database connection.

As long as I catch it, I simply have to do the following command:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

and its up and running in about 30 seconds.

I imagine this is not enough info to diagnose, but I am sure there is an error log or something I can pull which would be more useful.

One random thought - I have an embedded twitter feed that shows latest tweets. It happened today immediately after the tweet was posted. I have no idea if there is a connection and didn't pay attention the last few days when tweeting. Just thought I would throw it out there in case someone knows of a conflict.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: you can post this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `/var/log/mysql.err` or `/var/log/mysql.log`, also check your RAM and swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue for me was too little ram. I was running on 512 megs, and upgrading to 1 gig has fixed the issue.